# Shapes on line graph using stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm sure the answer is very simple but at the moment it eludes me. I want to make a line graph using `stat_summary()`, with different shapes for each group (representing an experimental condition) at each x-axis tick (representing a separate time point).

Here's the data

```
set.seed(124)
ID <- rep(1:12, times = 3)
Group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 12)
score <- rnorm(36, 25, 3)
session <- rep(c("s1","s2", "s3"), each = 12)

df <- data.frame(ID, Group, session, score)
```

Now I can get there by making a table of means for each time point. Like so.

```
gMeans <- aggregate(score ~ session + Group, data = df, mean)
```

And then graphing it like so.

```
pMeans <- ggplot(data = gMeans, aes(x = session, y = score, group = Group, shape = Group)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Group), size = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 5, fill = "white") +
  scale_color_hue(name = "Group", l = 30) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Group", values = c(23,22, 21)) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "Group") +
  theme_bw() 

pMeans
```

However I would like to be able to skip the step of having to make the table of means by using `stat_summary()`. I can get a similar graph with different line types, but I can't work out how to get the different shapes on each axis tick for each group. I tried the code below and many different permutations of `geom_point()` and `geom_line()`, but to no avail. How do I alter the code below to get output that looks like the output derived from the code above?

```
pline <- ggplot(df, aes(x=session, y=score, group = Group, shape = Group)) +
                stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", size=1.1, aes(linetype=Group, shape = Group)) +
                scale_shape_manual(values=c(1:3)) 

pline
```

Comment: A quick way is to add the function into your _point and _line calls: `ggplot(data = df, aes(x = session, y = score, group = Group, shape = Group)) +
    geom_line(aes(linetype = Group), size = 1, stat="summary", fun.y=mean) +
  geom_point(size = 5, fill = "white", stat="summary", fun.y=mean) `

Comment: Thank you for the tip @user20650. That was helpful, it added the shapes but despite the `fill = white` call in your `geom_point` layer, the shapes came out with a black fill. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: You need to add the scale_shape as in your example (    `scale_shape_manual(name = "Group", values = c(23,22, 21))`)

Comment: I wish _all_ the SO questions were this thorough, well-formatted and had equal effort put into making a reproducible example. This is awesome @llewmills.

Comment: Thanks again user20650. And thanks for noticing @hrbrmstr. I try to make it understandable for others who might have the same problem. Also I discovered early on that it increases my chances of getting an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should help and also clean up the legend:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(124)
ID <- rep(1:12, times = 3)
Group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), times = 12)
score <- rnorm(36, 25, 3)
session <- rep(c("s1","s2", "s3"), each = 12)

df <- data.frame(ID, Group, session, score)

gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x=session, y=score, group = Group, shape = Group))
gg <- gg + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="line", size=1.1, 
                        aes(linetype = Group), show.legend=FALSE)
gg <- gg + stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", size=5, 
                        aes(shape = Group), fill="white")
gg <- gg + scale_shape_manual(name = "Group", values = c(23, 22, 21))
gg <- gg + theme_bw() 
gg <- gg + theme(legend.key=element_blank())
gg
```

The lines were obscured, so it makes little sense to keep them in the legend. Since you used `stat_summary()` for the line (vs `geom_line()` with an embedded `stat="summary"` it's best to keep the idiom for the point geom as well IMO).

[image]